# Is this use of GADTs fully equivalent to existential types?

Tags: haskell, gadt, existential-type

[Existentially quantified data constructors](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#existentially-quantified-data-constructors) like

```
data Foo = forall a. MkFoo a (a -> Bool)
         | Nil
```

can be easily translated to GADTs:

```
data Foo where 
    MkFoo :: a -> (a -> Bool) -> Foo
    Nil :: Foo
```

Are there any differences between them: code which compiles with one but not another, or gives different results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are nearly equivalent, albeit not completely so, depending on which extensions you turn on.

First of all, note that you don't need to enable the `GADTs` extension to use the `data .. where` syntax for existential types. It suffices to enable the following lesser extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

With these extensions, you can compile

```
data U where
    U :: a -> (a -> String) -> U

foo :: U -> String
foo (U x f) = f x

g x = let h y = const y x
      in  (h True, h 'a')
```

The above code also compiles if we replace the extensions and the type definition with

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data U = forall a . U a (a -> String)
```

The above code, however, does *not* compile with the `GADTs` extension turned on! This is because `GADTs` also turns on the `MonoLocalBinds` extension, which prevents the above definition of `g` to compile. This is because the latter extension prevents `h` to receive a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#declaring-data-types-with-explicit-constructor-signatures):

> Notice that GADT-style syntax generalises existential types (Existentially quantified data constructors). For example, these two declarations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> data Foo = forall a. MkFoo a (a -> Bool)
> data Foo' where { MKFoo :: a -> (a->Bool) -> Foo' }
> ```

(emphasis on the word equivalent)

Comment: I did look at the GADT section as well as the existentially quantified constructor section before asking, but unfortunately not at this one.

Answer (score 4):

The latter isn't actually a GADT - it's an existentially quantified data type declared with GADT syntax. As such, it is identical to the former.

The reason it's not a GADT is that there is no type variable that gets refined based on the choice of constructor. That's the key new functionality added by GADTs.  If you have a GADT like this:

```
data Foo a where
    StringFoo :: String -> Foo String
    IntFoo :: Int -> Foo Int
```

Then pattern-matching on each constructor reveals additional information that can be used inside the matching clause.  For instance:

```
deconstructFoo :: Foo a -> a
deconstructFoo (StringFoo s) = "Hello! " ++ s ++ " is a String!"
deconstructFoo (IntFoo i)    = i * 3 + 1
```

Notice that something very interesting is happening there, from the point of view of the type system.  `deconstructFoo` promises it will work for *any* choice of `a`, as long as it's passed a value of type `Foo a`. But then the first equation returns a `String`, and the second equation returns an `Int`.

This is what you cannot do with a regular data type, and the new thing GADTs provide. In the first equation, the pattern match adds the constraint `(a ~ String)` to its context.  In the second equation, the pattern match adds `(a ~ Int)`.

If you haven't created a type where pattern-matching can cause type refinement, you don't have a GADT.  You just have a type declared with GADT syntax.  Which is fine - in a lot of ways, it's a better syntax than the basic data type syntax. It's just more verbose for the easiest cases.